# Why doesn't my html parser download the entire html documentation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to scrape the following page: https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:AAN

I want to the stock value below the name + abbreviation. However, when I run a script, it seems that `soup.find()` does not work because the entire html file is not being downloaded.

```py
main_url = "https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:AAN"

import requests
result = requests.get(main_url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find("div", class_ = "d-dquote-symbol").prettify())
```

I expect to see the `<div>` that contains the `<span>` with the correct stock value. However, the print returns "none" because the script cannot find this tag. I know it exists because I used inspect element to find the tag in the first place.

Comment: Inspect will also show dynamic elements. Use View Source to check if it's actually there.

Comment: Using the inspect feature of the browser shows the DOM the browsers *interpretation* of the the HTML that can also be *modified and extended by Java Script* code. All browsers have an other feature to show the actual unrenderer HTML source. That is what beautifulsoup sees and operates on.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the page you're scraping is not static.

you can see that it has a "spinner" before displaying the values, or by inspecting the `network` tab in your browser's debug tools.

`requests.get` doesn't make any "follow-up" requests so you only get the empty page.

to get the stock value (by HTML scraping...) you should use the request the site itself uses to get the stock value.

NOTE: it is better to look for an official API to get this kind of structured data.

Comment: do you have any suggestions for a specific API to use? If I don't use an API, how would I use the request that the site uses?

Comment: I think the most famous one is Yahoo Finance, here's one guide on how to use it: https://blog.rapidapi.com/how-to-use-the-yahoo-finance-api/

Answer (score 0):

You can use any browser simulator to get the quote. [pyppeteer](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html) can be a good choice to do the trick. The script will wait for the quote to be available and then parse it.

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

url = "https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:AAN/QUOTE"

async def get_quote(link):
    wb = await launch()
    page = await wb.newPage()
    await page.goto(link)
    await page.waitForSelector(".d-dquote-bigContainer [class^='d-dquote-x']")
    container = await page.querySelector(".d-dquote-bigContainer [class^='d-dquote-x']")
    quote = await page.evaluate('(element) => element.innerText', container)
    print(quote)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_quote(url))
```

Output at this moment:

```
60.09
```

Comment: When I run this code, I get the following error: error while loading shared libraries shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I guess you have not been able to install pyppeteer properly. Did you try running any of the example snippets out there to make sure you got pyppeteer working in your machine? Thanks.

Comment: I am running it off of a web python IDE. I think this is why there is an issue.